# How to make a Javascript string work with multiple file formats?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add gif emotes to a chat that my site has built in. At the moment it only works with .png file format.

I've tried replacing the **`.png'>`** part with **`.png | .gif'>`** and similar ways but didn't work.

```
emote: function(str) {
            var emo = ["biblethump", "kappa", "kreygasm", "pjsalt", "pogchamp", "fire", "rip", "failfish", "thumplove", "theilluminati", "cmonbruh", "lul", "ez", "bobtheshoplifter", "ree", "lambo", "fastercolorful", "kms", "glowbear", "pepelaserree", "feelsabdulman", "blobbanhammer", "success", "loveu"];
            for (var i = 0; i < emo.length; i++) {
                str = str.replace(new RegExp(emo[i] + "( |$)", "g"), "<img src='img/emotes/" + emo[i] + ".png'> ");
            }
            return str;
        },
```

Comment: How do you know which file extension is the correct one for a given `emo` element?

Comment: @CertainPerformance when typing the emo in the chat, for example "fire" it automatically replaces it with the image, since it grabs the img from the emotes folder. If the extension doesn't exist, the emote won't appear.

Comment: Ok, so how do you know which file extension is the correct one for a given `emo` element?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well, I can just add another variable called like `var emogif = ["thisisagif",]` and type the ones that are a gif in there, but I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML does not allow you to specify (png | gif). The reason for this is because the HTML img tag is simply making a request for the url you provide. Some solutions for this:

Have a lookup table in your javascript so you know what extension to use for a given emote:

```
const emoteExt = {
    biblethump: '.png',
    kappa: '.gif',
    kreygasm: '.png'
}
```

Your existing code would only need a small change:

```
"<img src='img/emotes/" + emo[i] + emoteExt[emo[i]] + "'> "
```

If you don't want to provide a lookup table on the client side, you can also handle this server side. The server that sends down the image can ignore the extension and send down whatever is available.

The server-side solution would not require code changes when new emotes or emote extensions are added but it requires a bit of know-how (and that you aren't using a static server).